# How can i specify switches on command line in tcl?

Tags: tcl, expect

If i have an expect script and i want to execute certain part of code depending on the requirement.suppose if i have some procedures in my code like below

```
proc ABLOCK { } {

}

proc BBLOCK { } {

}

proc CBLOCK { } {

}
```

then while executing the script if i can use some switches like.

```
./script -A ABLOCK #executes only ABLOCK
./script -A ABLOCK -B BBLOCK #executes ABLOCK and BBLOCK
./script -V  # just an option for say verbose output
```

where ABLOCK,BBLOCK,CBLOCK could be list of args `argv`

Comment: The most popular way to parse command line arguments is using [cmdline](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/cmdline.html), which is part of TCLLIB. Many more are listed at [http://wiki.tcl.tk/1730](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1730).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not:

```
foreach arg $argv {
    $arg
}
```

and run it as `./script ABLOCK BLOCK CBLOCK`

Someone could also pass `exit`, if you don't want that, check if it is valid:

```
foreach arg $argv {
    if {$arg in {ABLOCK BLOCK CBLOCK}} {
        $arg
    } else {
        # What else?
    }
}
```

For switches, you could to the same (if they don't require a parameter):

```
proc -V {} {
    set ::verbose 1
    # Enable some other output
}
```

If you need arguments to switches, you could do the following:

```
set myargs $argv
while {[llength $myargs]} {
    set myargs [lassign $myargs arg]
    if {[string index $arg 0] eq {-}} {
       # Option
       if {[string index $arg 1] eq {-}} {
           # Long options
           switch -exact -- [string range $arg 2 end]
               verbose {set ::verbose 1}
               logfile {set myargs [lassign $myargs ::logfile]}
           }
       } else {
           foreach opt [split [string range $arg 1 end] {}] {
               switch -exact $opt {
                   V {set ::verbose 1}
                   l {set myargs [lassign $myargs ::logfile]}
               }
           }
       }
    } else {
        $arg
    }
}
```